# WinRT logging to a file

Tags: c#, debugging, asynchronous, file-io, windows-runtime

I have been using `System.diagnose.Debug` to debug the bulk of my app but now I need to debug the behaviour when the OS is booted (We have running background tasks). This means we are not attached to the VS debugger so what I planned on doing was writing my debug to a file somewhere. In winRT ALL file IO seem to be async. And to use async the method containing it must be async and this just bubbles up through my calls untill everything now has an async marker (non-ideal). Is there a way to do file debug logging without going through all this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using [MetroLog](https://github.com/mbrit/MetroLog). It has a FileStreamingTarget target that makes it very easy to log stuff on a WinRT app.

If you still wanna roll out your own, you can take a look at their source code.

**Edit**

Also, you don't have to make every method `async`.
You can block and wait for the result, like this:

```
var folder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(Folder)
                                           .GetAwaiter()
                                           .GetResult();
var file = folder.GetFileAsync(Filename).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var content = FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Logging-Sample-for-Windows-0b9dffd7) logging sample on MSDN sample gallery by Can Bilgin. It's quite simple & doesn't use `async/await`.